# Discord bot reacts when specific user is tagged

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm new to programming and i'm trying to make a Discord bot for me and my friends, for now I have set up two commands, the first works fine, but the second one is the problem.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === `@usertag#0001`) {
    msg.channel.send(`<@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> don't tag me`);
  }
});
```

So what it should do is when a specific user is tagged it sends a message, the message sent from the bot is working (it tags the user who sent the message 3 times and then it says something else), but the part where the bot recognizes the tag doesn't work.

I tried by putting the Discord id, using the full @, and other stuff, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For this you could use the `message.mentions` method, and here is how you could use it for example:

```
// For Discord V13 'message' is deprecated and
// will be removed in the future, use 'messageCreate' instead.
client.on("message", msg => {
    // Disable messages from bot to avoid endless loops / replies
    if(msg.author.bot === true) return;

    // Check if anyone is mentioned.
    // Skip @everyone mentions to be checked.
    if(msg.mentions.users.size > 0 && msg.mentions.everyone === false) {
        if(msg.mentions.users.find(user => user.id === "ENTER USER ID HERE")) {
            msg.channel.send(`<@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> don't tag me!`);
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you! `!` I have tested this with Discord V13, i'm not 100% sure if this will work on Discord V12 as well.

Comment: hi, it kinda worked, if i answer with a normal string it works, but if i try to mention the message sender the bot crashes (i don't wanna use reply, just wanna tag him)

what i do is 
msg.channel.send(`<@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> heyyy`);

usually on a normal message ( something like !hello) it works fine, but in this case the bot crashes

Comment: @Marco can you tell me what error(s) you exactly get? I'll update my answer in a few.

Comment: msg.channel.send(`<@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> <@${msg.author.id}> Cosa mi taggi :poop:`);
            ^

ReferenceError: msg is not defined


in it's entirety the error it's too long, but i think the main part would be this, i don't know why it's saying it's not definied if it's working in the other messages

Comment: @Marco in my example I used `message` parameter, you could change `msg.author.id` to `message.author.id` then it should work ^^. I'll update my answer with yours.

Comment: before looking here i checked the error the error again and thought the same thing, i did it and it worked, honestly no idea why i have to put message instead of msg in this case but thanks a lot :)))

Comment: @Marco Glad it worked! There is no special reason why you have to put `message` instead of `msg`, these are parameters you have to define yourself. Some people prefer `msg` and others `message`, it's really up to you how you name your variables ^^.